# Remove script which is executed after load the page

Tags: javascript

There is a site with wall of topics. Anyone can write anything. But anyone can write JS script and this script will be executed with loading this site.

Something like `document.body.innerHTML = "";`.

I wrote also script which found every script in `<div>` with topics and rewrite its to empty string, but it does not work.

If I tested this script on the site (in console) with topics (before executed), it found scripts and rewrite its, but after post my script to this website, it does not work. Scripts will be executed after all.

Can I fix it before help from IT tech?

Comment: Removing javascript from a string is pretty much impossible. Browsers can even get it wrong. It's probably better to just escape the string before outputting it (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html).

Comment: @John Doe I don't know much but I think no one can execute the code without <script> tags. So why don't you remove all the <script> tags from the comments provided by the user. That can prevent any user provided JS code to be executed and browser will treat any JS code in comments as literal string.

Comment: @RK_15 You likely won't be able to cover all the cases where people could execute code from an unsanitized string. It's better just to sanitize it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add the user content as a text node. The content will show up exactly as the user typed it. Though if you're trying to include formatting (bold, italic, etc.), this won't work.

```js
const userContent = "<myScript>alert('here')</myScript>"

const userContentNode = document.createTextNode(userContent)

document.body.appendChild(userContentNode)
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

I had to use `<myScript>` instead of `<script>` because it looks like Stackoverflow does some kind of anti-XSS stuff for snippets.